# separating a table into subtables based on a value in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs 2008 like:

```
id type1 type2 type3 Score
1  N      H     H    2
2  H      N     N    1
3  N      L     H    2
4  L      L     H    3
5  N      L     N    1
6  N      N     N    0
```

Note that the data with N are normal, all others (L and H) are anormal for me. The score is calculated by `#L + #H`.

What I want is to groupby this table and show like:

```
count:3
id type1 type2 type3
4  L     L     H

count:2
id type1 type2 type3
1  N     H     H
3  N     L     H

count:1
id type1 type2 type3
2  H     N     N
5  N     L     N

count:0
id type1 type2 type3
6  N     N     N
```

So there needs to be 4 different table like that in a single page. What is the best way to provide this?

Edit: It is also OK to show them in one single matrix like grouping by the mentioned way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise creating a list.  Then, within this list create the table you want to display.  You can then group the list on Score Column (Row Group -> Group Properties -> General -> Group Expressions -> Add), which will display a separate table for each Score in your system.

The design would look like this

[image]

And then when it executes like this

[image]

You can play with look and feel, order etc, once you've got the basic structure working.  Hopefully this is helpful, let me know if you have further questions